# PHP - XML to Array's

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I need to convert a xml to arrays:

XML

```
?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <article>
    <a>TEST></a>
    <b>TEST2</b>
    <c>TEST3</c>
  </article>

  <article>
    <a>TEST4></a>
    <b>TEST5</b>
    <c>TEST6</c>
  </article>
</DocumentElement>
```

I need an Array like this:

```
$testArray = array(
        array('a' => TEST, 'b' => 'TEST2', 'c' => TEST3),
        array('a' => TEST4, 'b' => 'TEST5', 'c' => TEST6)
    );
```

My first attempts are:

```
$file = "product.xml";
$productArray = @simplexml_load_file($file) or
die ("ERROR loading file");
```

But with that method I get one Array.

Any suggestions on how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your structure of the XML is dynamic, you can create a couple of loops which extract the values along with the names of the elements and add them into a result array one by one.

```
$file = "product.xml";
$productArray = simplexml_load_file($file) or
     die ("ERROR loading file");
$articles = [];
foreach ( $productArray->article as $article )  {
    $newElement = [];
    foreach ( $article as $element )    {
        $newElement [ $element->getName() ] = (string)$element;
    }
    $articles[] = $newElement;
}

print_r($articles);
```

Gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => TEST>
            [b] => TEST2
            [c] => TEST3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => TEST4>
            [b] => TEST5
            [c] => TEST6
        )

)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help, if your problem is solved can you please mark it as answered. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
$productArray = @simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("ERROR loading file");
```

You will get an object.

if you want to loop through each article you can do this way

```
foreach($productArray ->children() as $article) { 
    echo $article->a. ", "; 
    echo $article->b. ", "; 
    echo $article->c. ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below goes through the XML of your question.

```
<?PHP
$link = 'yourxmlfile.xml'; //XML link
$xml = simplexml_load_file($link); //load xml


//Loop
foreach($xml -> article as $item){ 
    echo "<strong>A:</strong> ".utf8_decode($item ->a)."<br />";
    echo "<strong>B:</strong> ".utf8_decode($item ->b)."<br />";
    echo "<strong>C:</strong> ".utf8_decode($item ->c)."<br />";
    echo "<br />";
}
```